# unable to add hashtable to datagrid

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I am not sure what wrong I am doing, but based on the google searches, below code should work for inserting a hash into datagrid.
The data grid comes up with no values at all.
Sorry I am new to Powershell and struggling for quiet a while..

Below is code that I am trying to implement:

```
$Subs = Get-AzureRMSubscription
$counter = 1
$Hold = foreach($Sub in $Subs) {
$Entry = New-Object System.Object
$Entry | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Sr. No" -NotePropertyValue $counter
$Entry | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Subscription ID" -NotePropertyValue 
$Sub.ID
$Entry | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Name" -NotePropertyValue $Sub.Name

$Entry
$counter++
}
$Hold

foreach($Hashkey in $Hold.keys){
$tempno = $Hashkey.'Sr. No'
$tempid = $Hashkey.'Subscription ID'
$tempnm = $Hashkey.Name
$datagrid.Rows.Add($tempno, $tempid, $tempnm)
}
$form.Controls.Add($datagrid)
$form.showDialog()
```

Comment: `$Hold` is not a hashtable, it's an array of objects

Comment: Thank you Mark, It worked!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comment from Mathias, the issue is that you are treating `$Hold` as if its a hashtable, but its not, its actually a collection (array) of objects.

I think you can fix your code by just changing:

```
foreach($Hashkey in $Hold.keys)
```

To be:

```
foreach($Hashkey in $Hold)
```

`$Hold` does not have a `.Keys` property because it is not a hashtable.